# iterate over an array and delete elements conditionally

Tags: ruby

The following logic:

Iterate over the URLs array and If the HTTP request with the given URL does not timeout, continue. If the URL times out, remove it from the array and continue with the next one until the array is exhausted.

Has been implemented in the following way:

```
@urls.delete_if do |url|
  begin
    doc = perform_request(some_params)
    break
  rescue TimeoutError
    Rails.logger.warn("URL #{url} times out, will be removed from list")
    true
  end
end
```

Anyone for a cleaner solution? Basically, I want to iterate over an array and remove elements from it if there is a timeout, but if the URL works loop should end and app should continue processing.

Comment: Specifically,  hate the break in there - maybe someone can propose a cleaner solution.

Comment: Btw "true" in the rescue can be removed, not needed.

Comment: if not needed just edit the question! I have a doubt, why do you want to modify inplace @urls? wouldn't do a functional solution?

Answer (score 3):

note : your `break` is useless, because if the block returns a falsey value, the url is kept.

Maybe it can just be a bit more expressive ?

```
def timeouts?( url )
  perform_request( url ) && false 
rescue TimeoutError
  true
end

@urls.delete_if {|url| timeouts?( url ) }
```

You could even make `timeouts?` a method on your `@urls` objects, for extra readability :

```
@urls.delete_if( &:timeouts? )
```

if you want to keep @tokland's functionnal approach, just use :

```
@kept_urls = @urls.reject{|url| timeouts?( url ) }
```

however, it would not be fully "functionnal", because `timeouts` may not return the same results with the same arguments, depending on the execution environment.

Comment: Maybe calling the function `timesout?` instead of `timeouts?` would semantically be better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a functional approach (no in-place updates):

```
url, doc = @urls.map_detect do |url|
  begin
    [url, perform_request(some_params)]
  rescue TimeoutError
    Rails.logger.warn("URL #{url} timed out")
    false
  end
end
```

This snippet uses the custom abstraction [Enumerable#map_detect](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms#Enumerable#map_detect) (see also [Facets](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#find_yield-instance_method))

You can then use `url` to update `@urls`, but it's better not to mix the algorithm (even if it's so simple) with the updates required by the app.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [drop_while](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-drop_while) to get rid of iterative operator `break`:

```
@urls = @urls.drop_while do |url|
  begin
    doc = perform_request(some_params)
    false
  rescue TimeoutError
    Rails.logger.warn("URL #{url} times out, will be removed from list")
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem is `doc` won't be visible outside the block's scope.